# Strange behaviour for Sticky div

Tags: html, css, sticky

I am trying to get my div sticky positioned. I got confused with the strange behaviour basis the positioning of the div. As per the above code, it is working as expected however if I try to shift my sticky div inside div with background orange then it doesn't work. Could someone help me with the explanation for this strange behaviour.

```css
div.one {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Sticky Element: Scroll Down to See the Effect</h2>
<p>Scroll down this page to see how sticky positioning works.</p>
<div style="background:red; padding:10px">
  <div>
    <div style="background:orange">
      <p>Just some random text
        <p>
          //If sticky div (class="one") moved here then doesn't work
    </div>
    <div class="one">This is sticky</div>
    <div class="two" style="background:green;height:1200px">
      <h1>Remaining</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position, "The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the document, and then offset relative to its nearest scrolling ancestor and containing block (nearest block-level ancestor)". In your example the ancestor is the key

Comment: Thanks @j08691. If I have a scenario where sticky div needs to be shifted, how can I fix it?